# What does it mean ? I found it from my logs

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, code-injection

I kept all logs from visitors with mySQL. Where it from URL and which URL visit. I found this one.

myweb.com/read.php?id=2349 and(SeLeCt 1 FrOm(SeLeCt count(*),CoNcAt((SeLeCt(SeLeCt UnHeX(HeX(CoNcAt(char(33,126,33),0x4142433134355a5136324457514146504f4959434644,char(33,126,33))))) FrOm information_schema.TaBlEs LiMiT 0,1),floor(rand(0)*2))x FrOm information_schema.TaBlEs GrOuP By x)a) and 1=1&aid=3&bid=18

What does it means ? and What is it doing with my website ?

Comment: Looks like someone has been attempting to hack your site.

Comment: Looks like it's trying to exploit SQL injection

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787558/sql-injection-attack-what-does-this-do

Answer (score 0):

A simple SQL-Injection attempt. Do the following things:

1. check your webserver and application configuration if you are vulnarable to this kind of attempt. (e.g. your application parses the SQL and it is executed using your database, that would be bad)
2. Fix your configuration
3. Check if this attempt caused any harm.
4. At least the attacker now knows, that you own this system, because you published this very specific value here.

`SeLeCt
  UnHeX(
   HeX(
    CoNcAt(
     char(33,126,33)
     ,0x414...4644
     ,char(33,126,33)
    )
   )
  );`

Will return something like

`!~!ABC145...!~!`

Is this in the combination with the rest of the statement an issue on your database?