# duplicate-key error in mysql triggered by count(*) on group by

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection, mysql-error-1064

hi every one  i was reading a sans book about blind sql injection

the author of the book mention that if you want to trigger an error in mysql

use this  query  and  inject it in the target

```
1 and (select 1 from (select count(*),concat(/*your malicious query here*/,floor(rand(0)*2)x from users group by x) a)
```

and  he says (author) that `count(*)` on a `group by "floor(rand(0)*2)"` causes a duplicate key in internal table and display the key

My questions:
first why he put the x there ?

second what is duplicate key in internal table error and what query causes it other then this one and how `count(*)` on a `group by "floor(rand(0)*2)"` causes it to happen

Comment: Are you sure you copied it correctly? I think `x` should be after the next `)`. Then it's an alias for the `concat()` expression.

Comment: I'm not sure you can rely on MySQL showing you anything.  More typically, injection would be used to run malicious DML stuff, like dropping an entire table.

Comment: ya i copied correctly do u want a screenshot

Comment: this is a screenshot https://imgur.com/a/SHF6T @Barmar

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's blind sql so is not showing anything u have to use some method to know what happen like time method or error method

Comment: You have an extra parenthesis after `x` before `from users`

Comment: ya u are right wowo that's  what i called   professional @Barmar

Comment: i edit it @Barmar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787558/sql-injection-attack-what-does-this-do covers this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is an alias for the expression `floor(rand(0)*2)`, so it can be references in `GROUP BY x`.

"duplicate key in an internal table" sounds like a description of a MySQL bug that occurs when it's trying to process this query.

Comment: can you give me any research about this bug I want to read more about it

Comment: i will vote up for your work but i will wait for someone to give me a good explanation

Comment: i will take a look there and i will ask in mysql forum if they have one