# query Level in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, sql-injection

hey everyone I was reading some books about SQL injection and the author  started throwing some  terms I couldn't understand so can you help me understand them
my questions:
query level in the database what it means?

by the way
the author talks about sqlmap  specifically how it works and he mentions a file named  payload.xml and in this file, there is a level of the query used by Sqlmap to reduce the number of the query in the SQL injection process u can take a look at this screenshot from the book https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAA6u.jpg

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the expressions have been explained somewhere in the book. Please, read it to the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is purely terminology for sqlmap.

The sqlmap tool tests common vectors of SQL injection. The level of a test is intended to reflect the difficulty of detecting SQL injection from each vector.

When you invoke the sqlmap tool to run a test, you can tell it to perform tests for additional vectors of input. This is just a way to allow you to enable more tests when you invoke the sqlmap tool.

I skimmed the sqlmap documentation (https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage) and got the following summary:

- Level 1: test all GET and POST parameters
- Level 2: additionally test the `Cookie` http header
- Level 3: additionally test the `User-Agent` and `Referer` http headers
- Level 4:
- Level 5: additionally test the `Host` http header

Answer (score -2):

It is quite possible you mean a pseudocolumn that Oracle uses in a hierarchical query for identifying the level itself. It is also good to mention that this is in numeric format.

But as Maciej said, it should be explained in the book, perhaps you missed it and therefore my advice is to reread related chapters.

Comment: what if i tell u this is the only page that talk about this term this book is crazy i have to ask 2 time in the same day look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088405/duplicate-key-error-in-mysql-triggered-by-count-on-group-by